# Get position of word from html code given its starting and end index calculated from normal text

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have `contenteditable` div and would like to know the index of character typed in it with respect to html code.
For example:

```
<div id="editableDiv" contenteditable="true">
    the @twitter
</div>
```

The sentence is formatted like this: **the** @twitter
I can calculate the string position in sentence using below function. This is being called on `@` keyed down (start index) and on `space bar` key down (end index - 1)

```
getCaretPosition : function(){
       var element = document.getElementById("editableDiv");
       var caretOffset = 0;
       if (typeof window.getSelection != "undefined") {
            var range = window.getSelection().getRangeAt(0);
            var preCaretRange = range.cloneRange();
            preCaretRange.selectNodeContents(element);
            preCaretRange.setEnd(range.endContainer, range.endOffset);
            caretOffset = preCaretRange.toString().length;
        } else if (typeof document.selection != "undefined" && document.selection.type != "Control") {
            var textRange = document.selection.createRange();
            var preCaretTextRange = document.body.createTextRange();
            preCaretTextRange.moveToElementText(element);
            preCaretTextRange.setEndPoint("EndToEnd", textRange);
            caretOffset = preCaretTextRange.text.length;
        }
        return caretOffset;
    }
```

Start index is 5 and end index is 12 for the word *@twitter* in above sentence.

I would now like to get the index of the same word from innerHTML of the div `editableDiv`.

InnerHTML: `<b>the</b> @twitter`
Input index of the word @twitter: (5,12)
Output ->
start Index : 12
end index: 19

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah ... You can use RegEx to do so, or split the data into array and analyze it.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Bla!</title>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
            function boldBeforeWord(word) {
                var txt = document.getElementById('divContent').innerHTML
                var txtArray = txt.split(' ');
                for (var i=1; i< txtArray.length; i++) {
                    if (word ==  txtArray[i].trim()) {
                        txtArray[i-1] = "<b>" + txtArray[i-1] + "</b>";
                    } else {
                        console.log (txtArray[i]);
                    }
                }
                document.getElementById('divContent').innerHTML = txtArray.join (' ');
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id='divContent'>
            This is div with content.  I'll try to parse it's content, add bold to any word before @guy <br>
            Is this helpfull? I'm asking as @guy
        </div>
        <button onclick = 'boldBeforeWord("@guy");'> Click to bold </button>
    </body>
</html>
```

In the example I've simply made it to all the words, but you can use the "indexOf" to make sure you on the right position inside the array.

Comment: Thanks Dafny. I was able replace word with some modification but issue is how will I be able to maintain index of the word that I am interested in replacing in an split up array? The solution replaces all occurrences of word with the new string. Above all, your solution is indeed helpful. Happy New Year.

Comment: I was finally able to solve the issue with small modification to your answer. Happy New Year. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The answer is quite obvious: **text doesn't contains html tags**.

Complete answer you'll find here: [CodeProject: Get position of word from html code given its starting and end index calculated from normal text](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/703802/Get-position-of-word-from-html-code-given-its-star#answer1)